# Batch File Store Line Variables And Sum Them Up

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

My input file Count.txt contains the following:

```
] /Count 1
] /Count 2
```

I am trying to add the numeric characters at the end of each line and store it to another file or store it to another variable.
I am not able to do it with the following batch file script:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%i in ('findstr Count Count.txt') do (
set /a count=%%i + %count%
echo !count! > finalcount.txt
) 
endlocal
```

The output I am getting is 2.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0

(for /f "tokens=3" %%i in ('findstr "Count" Count.txt') do (
set /a count+=%%i
echo !count! 
))> finalcount.txt
```

Comment: Thanks Endoro. This is working. However, I can't understand why finalcount.txt contains 1 then another line for the correct number, 3

Comment: you can remove `> finalcount.txt` from the script to see, whats going on. The `for` loop runs for every line in `finalcount.txt`. If you only need the last result, just move `> finalcount.txt` before  `echo` : `> finalcount.txt echo !count!`.

Comment: `(code)>filename` writes a new file containing anything `ECHO`ed in `code`. `echo !count!` shows the run-time value of `count` as it changes. In the original, the value of `count` was being set to (read from file) + (value of count at PARSE-TIME); then the changed value was being written to a new version of the file in each loop. Changing the `set` to `set /a count=%%i + !count!` or `set /a count+=%%i` would both accomplish the required result. `count` would contain the sum at the end of the loop, so `echo !count! > finalcount.txt` or `echo %count% > finalcount.txt
` after the final `)` works.